# Kubuntu 11.10 mobile broadband option is disabled

Tags: bluetooth, internet-connection

I am using Sony Vaio VPCEB44EN.

I had installed Kubuntu 11.10 and configured my Samsung mobile phone there (adding Bluetooth device was successfully done.), but when I am trying to configure mobile broadband the option was disabled.

I don't know what the reason.

Answer (score 1):

The Bluetooth client which is installed in kubuntu only supports file transfer between devices, not any internet connection.